# login multiusuario no ejecuta la pagina que es

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, login

buen dia tengo un problema
resulta que estoy haciendo un login multiusuario ya que es 2 el administrador y 1 el auxiliar administrativo el problema es que cualquier eleccion que coloque me manda a la pagina admin.php que es la de administrador y cuando el auxiliar se conecta no me manda a admin2.php

aqui dejo el codigo de verifica.php

```
    <?php
//aqui acavo de quitar mi conexion    
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Error connecting to database. ".mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    session_start();
    
    $usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($sql_connection, $_POST['usuario']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($sql_connection, $_POST['password']);
    
    if (!$usuario || !$password) {
        echo "Both fields must be filled out.";
        return;
    }
    
    $query = "SELECT levely from uscmg WHERE usuario='$usuario' AND clave='$password'";
    
    $result = mysqli_query($sql_connection, $query);
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    
    
    
    
    
    
    if ($rows == 1) {
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
        header("Location: admin.php");
    } else if($rows == 2) 
    {
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
        header("Location: admin2.php");
    
    } 
    
    
    
    
    else {
        
        
        echo'<script type="text/javascript">
        alert("intentelo de nuevo O solicita registro");
        window.location.href="index.php";
        </script>';
    
    
    }
```

cabe mencionar que mi tabla en la columna lovely tiene varchar ()
no se si eso afecte tambien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función `mysqli_num_rows()` devuelve la cantidad de filas encontradas y, si estás colocando datos de usuario correctamente, siempre devolverá 1, sin importar qué tipo de usuario es.

```
$query = "SELECT levely from uscmg WHERE usuario='$usuario' AND clave='$password'";

$result = mysqli_query($sql_connection, $query);
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($rows == 1) {
    // Leer consulta
    $datos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    // Comparar dato
    if($datos['levely'] == 1) {
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
        header("Location: admin.php");
    } else {
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
        header("Location: admin2.php");
    }
    // Finalizar ejecución de script
    exit;
} else {
    // usuario incorrecto
}
```

Comment: gracias gracias gracias oye y no das cursos por hay